# Cinnamon show up a menu bar on top of the screen

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.10

I recently installed Cinnamon 1.2 on Ubuntu 11.10. But it show a menu on top of the screen if I choose to use file manager handle the desktop.

Following is a screenshot. Could anyone help me get rid of it? I tried to reinstall, remove & install. That does not work.

[image]

Comment: Answer my own question, after some googling, I found the answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/66591/nautilus-desktop-folder-menu-bar-and-folders-show-up-on-secondary-screen
Removing appmenu stuff it works. It appears that this is not a problem specific to Cinnamon but Ubuntu's attempt to copy Mac OS X's global menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn that menu off or on in cinnamon settings > desktop : there you have a checkbox : "have file manager handle the desktop" which does just what you need